# python xyz data transformation for surface plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spatial, surface

I want to plot a 3D surface in matplotlib from xy and z data. For this I need to do a seemingly simple data transformation but I am unsure on how to proceed.

My x and y data are uniform integers because it will be the surface of an image. 
My data is present in the form of a 512x512 numpy array. The values of the array are the z values, and the indexes are the x and y values respectively.

So if `arr` is my array, `arr[x, y]` would give my `z`. The form just looks like this:

```
z z z z ... z (512 columns)
z z z z ... z
z z z z ... z
z z z z ... z
. . . .
. . . .
z z z z (512 rows)
```

How do I get my data in the form of three columns x, y, z so I can do the surface plot? It should look like this after the transform:

```
  x | y | z
  ---------
  0 | 0 | z
  1 | 0 | z
  2 | 0 | z
  . | . | .
  . | . | .
511 | 0 | z
  0 | 1 | z
  1 | 1 | z
  2 | 1 | z
  . | . | .
  . | . | .
```

I tried to work with `np.meshgrid` and `np.flatten` but can't get it to work the way I want. Maybe theres an even easier pandas solution to this. Or maybe I can even plot it with the original form of the data?

Any suggestion is appreciated :)

Comment: For anyone reading this at a later point: I used `plt.plot_surface` to plot. For this, the end data format is wrong and you will get an error. The original format is correct for plotting a surface. Additionally you need two `np.meshgrids` (512x512) for the x and y values. (`x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(z.shape[0]), np.arange(z.shape[1])`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `np.meshgrid` like this:

```
# Make coordinate grids
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(arr.shape[0]), np.arange(arr.shape[1]), indexing='ij')
# Flatten grid and data and stack them into a single array
data = np.stack([x.ravel(), y.ravel(), arr.ravel()], axis=1)
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(arr.shape[0]), np.arange(arr.shape[1]), indexing='ij')
data = np.stack([x.ravel(), y.ravel(), arr.ravel()], axis=1)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  1]
 [ 0  2  2]
 [ 0  3  3]
 [ 1  0  4]
 [ 1  1  5]
 [ 1  2  6]
 [ 1  3  7]
 [ 2  0  8]
 [ 2  1  9]
 [ 2  2 10]
 [ 2  3 11]]
```

EDIT:

Actually, if you want to have your final array such that `x` values increase first (as in the example you gave), you could do it like this:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(arr.shape[0]), np.arange(arr.shape[1]), indexing='xy')
data = np.stack([x.ravel(), y.ravel(), arr.T.ravel()], axis=1)
```

In this case you would get:

```
[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  4]
 [ 2  0  8]
 [ 0  1  1]
 [ 1  1  5]
 [ 2  1  9]
 [ 0  2  2]
 [ 1  2  6]
 [ 2  2 10]
 [ 0  3  3]
 [ 1  3  7]
 [ 2  3 11]]
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. Could you give me some more insight on how `np.ravel` is different than `np.flatten`?

Comment: @cripcate They are basically the same, but [`flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) will always return a new array, while [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) only makes a copy if necessary. In this case, `data` will always be a new array, so the result would be the same, but you (potentially) save some intermediate copies.

Comment: alright! The problem in my thought process was aligning the 3 arrays. I thought I could only join them in a way that increases x and y at the same time. I will remember `np.stack` for the next time :)